# HTML5 feature check "Download attribute"

Tags: html, download, attributes

I'm using HTML5 feature ["download"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

How to check browser support HTML5 this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I found [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (Modernizr.adownload ) {
    alert("This browser supports HTML5 download!");
    }
</script>
```

But if have better solutions, please offer